# powershell How to capture 'left side' of the -replace regex?

Tags: powershell, replace

First time posting.

i have the following code to replace the suffix of an email and its working fine

replace all characters after @ sign with @testdomain.com

```
$a = 'john.doe@domain.com'
$b = $a -replace "[?=@].*", '@testdomain.com'
$b
john.doe@testdomain.com
```

what i would like to do, is to capture the actual left side 'source' regex expression to a variable, which would be @domain.com so that i know what i;m replacing and i don;t know how to do it.

Sorry if this had been posted before.

Thank you

Comment: `$a -replace '^.*(?=@)', 'jane.doe'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if this is possible using only the `-replace` operator and without the use of `-match` which would store the capture group on the `$Matches` automatic variable.

This is how you could do it using the [`regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) class directly:

```
$a = 'john.doe@domain.com'
$Capture = @{}

$b = [regex]::Replace($a, "[?=@].*", {
    param($s)
    
    '@testdomain.com'
    $Capture.Value = $s.Value
})
```

```
$b # => john.doe@testdomain.com
$Capture.Value # => @domain.com
```

---

This what I could think using only `-replace`, adding a delimiter (`//` in this case) to the replaced string followed by the capture group `$0` and then splitting the replacement. Though, this is obviously not a robust solution.

```
$a = 'john.doe@domain.com'
$b, $capture = $a -replace "[?=@].*", '@testdomain.com//$0' -split '//'
```

```
$b # => john.doe@testdomain.com
$capture # => @domain.com
```

Comment: You are a genius, i knew this was 'out-of-my-league' powershell skills :), it works perfectly. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @RobertK Thank you :) and happy to help. Now I'm wondering if this is possible using only `-replace` lol.

Comment: If maybe someone at Microsoft could answer this, as i struggled with this for few days as i needed to save those old domains to a file for save keeping.

Comment: @RobertK see my update, obviously, I would not recommend using it hehe

Comment: thanks for diggin further, however your first answer works perfect. I;m keeping it in my tips and tricks file.

Answer (score 0):

To change the user part you can replace `^.*(?=@)`:

```
PS ~> $a = 'john.doe@domain.com'
PS ~> $a -replace '^.*(?=@)', 'jane.doe'
jane.doe@domain.com
```

The `(?=@)` construct is known as a *lookahead*, and describes a zero-length string at the position immediately before the `@`.

Comment: I think he is trying to capture `$0` in a variable.

Comment: Yes exactly, i only would like to capture $0, in other words how can i see what the actual source replace search is, which in my case should show @domain.com string and not what is left in the original string. Hope this makes sense.